# How to update UserControl in another UserControl in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ascx

I have problem with updating usercontrol in another usercontrol.

Example Code:

```
UserControl MyCart1 = (UserControl)Page.FindControl("MyCart1");
UpdatePanel up_shoppingcart = (UpdatePanel)MyCart1.FindControl("up_shoppingcart");
                    up_shoppingcart.Update();
```

This code shows **Object reference not set to an instance of an object** error

Comment: Are you using MasterPage ?

Comment: why upvote? I saw this frequently with no apparent reasons.

Comment: Yes I'm using master page

Comment: Could you provide markup of controls?

Comment: I agree with @David, the NRE error is very descriptive, and i can see at least 3 places where it could have come from

Comment: People are trying to improve your post stop editing back to the bad formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to determine which of the three lines of code that you provided, throws the exception. This can easily done using debugger.
2. `FindControl` method searches only immediate children controls. You can write a recursive version of it to search deeper.

)

```
public Control FindControlDeep(Control parent, string id) 
{
    Control result = parent.FindControl(id);
    if (result == null)
    {
        for (int iter = 0; iter < parent.Controls.Count; iter++)
        {
            result = FindControlDeep(parent.Controls[iter], id);
            if (result != null)
                break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```